# Google AdWords and Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-ads-api

So I've got a project in Laravel 5.2, and I have to use Google Ads here. How should I request necessary files and libraries in my controllers?

For example, I have `/var/www/project/app/controllers/Controller.php`, and all Google provided src, examples etc. are stored in `/var/www/project/public/ads` folder. Then, from my Controller.php I want to get list of campaigns available in my account.

What should I write in the head of the controller? Some `use` or `require_once`? For now I have only these two:

```
require_once public_path('ads') . '/init.php';
require_once ADWORDS_UTIL_VERSION_PATH . '/ReportUtils.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp it looks like those are included simply like `use AdWordsUser`, `use Selector` and so on. That was easy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm creating a project which requires google ads data so I've created a package to make it a bit easier.

For those who it might be useful, it's the link: https://github.com/Edujugon/laravel-google-ads

Comment: When providing an answer, it is more helpful to include sufficient details, in case the link goes dead at a future point. Granted this it a github repository, but it would be more helpful to provide a basis for your response rather than just the link.